# Return undefined JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, undefined

I'm working on a JS exercise and I'm trying to return undefined when the given array contains a string, but instead it's returning NaN. What would be the best way for it to return undefined? Any help is appreciated!

```
function cubeOdd(arr) {
    var count = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      if(arr[i]==="") {
          return undefined;
      }
      else if(arr[i] % 2 !== 0) {
          count += Math.pow(arr[i],3);
      }
  }
  return count;
}
cubeOdd([2,3,4,'g']);
```

Comment: Did you try call `cubeOdd(['']);` with empty string?)

Comment: you compare to an empty String, but `"g" !== ""`. Check out `typeof` or `isNaN()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `'g' !== ''` Use `typeof` For example `typeof arr[i] !== 'number'` or `typeof arr[i] === 'string'`

```js
function cubeOdd(arr) {
    var count = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      if(typeof arr[i] !== 'number') {
          return undefined;
      }
      else if(arr[i] % 2 !== 0) {
          count += Math.pow(arr[i],3);
      }
  }
  return count;
}
console.log(cubeOdd([2,3,4,'g']), cubeOdd([2,3,4]));
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> arr[i]===""
> ```

That tests to see if it is an **empty string**, not any string.

To test for that:

```
typeof arr[i] === "string"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the variable is a `string` using `typeof myVariable`.

You were using `arr[i]===""` which check if `arr[i]` is an empty string

```js
function cubeOdd(arr) {
    var count = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      if(typeof arr[i] === 'string')
        return undefined;
      else if(arr[i] % 2 !== 0)
          count += Math.pow(arr[i],3);
  }
  return count;
}

console.log(cubeOdd([2,3,4,'g']));
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply replace the following line with

```
 if(arr[i]==="") {

if(typeof arr[i] === 'string') {
```

Currently, you are only checking if the value of the array is an empty string, but you want to check its type to make sure its a string.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use the prototype like type checking. It will work cross browser. Below is your updated code and I am assuming that array will return undefined if value is not Number

```
function cubeOdd(arr) {
    var count = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      if(Object.prototype.toString.call(arr[i])!=="[object Number]") {
          return undefined;
      }
      else if(arr[i] % 2 !== 0) {
          count += Math.pow(arr[i],3);
      }
  }
  return count;
}
cubeOdd([2,3,4,'g']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Issue is with your if condition. You're checking for an empty string. simply use

> isNaN()

```
    function cubeOdd(arr) {
    var count = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      if(isNaN(arr[i])) {
          return undefined;
      }
      else if(arr[i] % 2 !== 0) {
          count += Math.pow(arr[i],3);
      }
  }
  return count;
}
cubeOdd([2,3,4,'g']);
```

isNaN is a global javascript function which checks whether a given value **is not a number**. 
Reference : [isNaN() API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN)

PS : Only the condition of your code snippet has been changed.